# Strange line in django_cron

Tags: python, django, django-cron

I'm using this instruction http://django-cron.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html and can't understand meaning of "a unique code" line.

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule

class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 120 # every 2 hours

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'my_app.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
        pass    # do your thing here
```

Can anyone explain me what this line do?

```
code = 'my_app.my_cron_job'    # a unique code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at code [here](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron/blob/master/django_cron/__init__.py#L115):

```
def make_log(self, *messages, **kwargs):
    cron_log = self.cron_log

    cron_job      = getattr(self, 'cron_job', self.cron_job_class)
    cron_log.code = cron_job.code
```

we can understand, that this "unique code" denote particular cron task. Every time your cron task is executed, `CronJobLog` instance is created with `cron_log.code = cron_job.code`.

So, it is possible to [filter](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron/blob/master/django_cron/__init__.py#L79) the logs, that belongs to particular task:

```
last_job = CronJobLog.objects.filter(code=cron_job.code).latest('start_time')
```

That is why it must be unique, to not mix logs from one cron task with another.
I suppose it has the same purpose as id, but this code has meaningful value.